# How to map an Int database field to a Boolean Entity Framework model field?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

An `Int` field is used (for compatibility with other DBMSes and programming languages) to store a `Boolean` value in the database. How am I to customize the database-first generated Entity Framework model (which maps an `Int` field to `Int32` by default) to make sure it will use 1/0 (instead of "true"/"false") in SQL queries generated while using `Boolean` type on the application side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One work around is to use another Boolean  property in the model which is not mapped to the DB. And in that property set method you can set the integer value to the int property.

```
//EF Generated/Poco Do not Modify
public partial MyTable
{
  public int MyField { get; set; }
}
```

Since these are partial classes create another file

```
public partial MyTable
{
  public bool MyBoolField
  {
    get
    {
      return this.MyField != 0;
    }
    set
    {
      if (value)
      {
        this.MyField = 1;
      }
      else 
      {
        this.MyField = 0;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But you can't use that property in LINQ-to-Entities queries. Is there any way to achieve this? Define a conversion in the EDMX somehow?